# Problems with JUnit testing in IntelliJ IDEA - Class not found

Tags: java, android, junit, intellij-idea

I'm trying to do some JUnit testing in IntelliJ IDEA. When I have a pure Java project the testing works fine. However I have a Android project I want to test on. The project contains both pure Java files and Android files. This error comes from trying to test a non Android class in a Android project. The non-android class is in the same test package as the Android test classes.

When I have my dependencies structured like this:
[image]

I get the following error:
[image]

I looked at another thread here on Stackoverflow and that said to put JUnit above the Android API in the dependencies list. When I try that I only get:

Class not found: "com.edit.mouseophonic.app.tests.TestClass"
Process finished with exit code 1

I have no idea how to solve this. 
All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Use additional module for andoidTests which you can create in intellij idea http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/testing-android-applications.html

Another option using maven-android-plugin https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/ and use appropriate dependencies. I prefer second.